# Approximate answer to Max-SMT (bitvector) query

Tags: approximation-algorithms, sat, max2sat

I have a problem that could be completely solved as Max-SMT instances in the theory of quantifier-free bit-vectors, but it apparently is too complex to be tractable with current Max-SMT technology.  My application in practice could tolerate a fair amount of error, so I'm interested in the following problem: "Satisfy as many clauses as possible while terminating in *x* minutes." How would I go about approaching this? Is there a way I can leverage existing solvers?

Comment: One natural heuristic would be to randomly sample a subset of the constraints, then apply the Max-SMT solver to the resulting subset.

Comment: Some of the MaxSMT and MaxSAT solvers are "anytime" algorithms. They internally compute a sequence of approximations until they find one that cannot be improved (i.e. the optimum). So this should be possible in principle.

Comment: The yearly MaxSAT evaluation (https://maxsat-evaluations.github.io/2018/) lists an "incomplete track", which seems to feature exactly this kind of algorithm.